# Can I map an action method that returns Object in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-rest-plugin

I've used Struts2 to map actions to the methods that return `String`. Can I use other types? What types are possible to use?

I found that code using a REST plugin

```
// Handles /orders/{id} GET requests
public HttpHeaders show() {
    model = orderManager.findOrder(id);
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("show")
        .withETag(model.getUniqueStamp())
        .lastModified(model.getLastModified());
}
```

It shows that it maps to method `show` that returns `HttpHeaders`. And it's not a `String`. How it works?

Comment: Q: Can I map an action method that returns Object in Struts 2? A: Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework has features that allows to return not only `String`. You can return an instance of the `Result` directly from the action method instead of a `String.` For example

```java
public Result method() {
  //todo implementation is here  
}
```

If needed to return multiple types you can set return type as `Object`.

```java
public Object method() {
    Object resultCode = "success";
    if (something) {
        resultCode = new StrutsResultSupport();
    }
    return resultCode ;
}
```

About the rest method `HttpHeaders`  is a interface that doesn't extend `Result`, so it shouldn't be used as a result type.

Comment: Wrong again. *HttpHeaders is a interface that doesn't extend Result, so it shouldn't be used as a result type.*

Comment: It depends on implementation of `ActionInvocation` - REST plugin provides its own that's why it can handle `HttpHeaders`